# Doing an Upsert on nested List of objects using Reactive Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a relatively nested domain object for Orders that have a list of OrderItem which in turn have a list of Suppliers.  I want to do an upsert so that new Orders can be added and their corresponding orders are not present. The problem is I do not know how to deal with the updates for the nested collections. I am using Spring Boot 3 and Reactive Mongo. Is it possible to update at the Entity level, i.e update the OrderItem as an object instead of having to update the individual fields?

Here is the object model

```java
     // Order class
     import lombok.Data;
     import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
    
     import java.util.List;
    
    
     @Document(collection = "order")
     @Data
     public class Order {
    
        @Id
        String orderId;
        List<OrderItem> orderItemList;
    }
```

```java
     // OrderItem class
     import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
     import lombok.Data;
     import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
     import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
        
     import java.math.BigDecimal;
     import java.util.List;
        
     @Data
     @NoArgsConstructor
     @AllArgsConstructor
     @Document(collection = "order-item")
     public class OrderItem {
        
       @Id
       String orderItemId;
       BigDecimal price;
       String partNumber;
       String description;
       int quantityInStock;
       List<Supplier> suppliers;
     }
```

```java
     import lombok.Data;
     import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
    
     @Document(collection = "supplier")
     @Data
     public class Supplier {
    
       @Id
       String supplierId;
       String supplierName;
       String supplierPartNumber;
    }
```

Here are the beginnings of the code to perform the Upsert. The parts that are missing are the nested objects pieces, which I have no idea to do: I believe the rest of the code is fine, except of course the missing parts of nested objects. Ideally, I would like to use the whole entity in the update, something like update("$[orderItems].orderItem", orderItem) but I don't know if that is possible and what syntax to use if it is possible.

```java
     import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
     import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.BulkOperations;
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
     import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
    
     import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
     import java.util.List;
    
     @Service
     @RequiredArgsConstructor
     @Slf4j
     public class OrderService {
    
        private final MongoOperations mongoOperations;
        private final static String ORDER_COLLECTION = "orders";
    
        public void upsertOrders(List<Order> orders, List<OrderItem> orderItems) {
            try {
    
                if (!ordersItems.isEmpty()) {
                    BulkOperations bulkTemplateOperations = mongoOperations.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, ORDER_COLLECTION);
                    for (Order order : orders) bulkTemplateOperations.upsert(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(order.getOrderId())), createOrderUpdate(order));
                    bulkTemplateOperations.execute();
                }
    
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Failed to update orders collection  {}",e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            }
        }
    
    
        protected Update createOrderUpdate(Order order) {
            Update update =  new Update();
            update.set("orderId", order.getOrderId());
            // how to do for OrderItems
            return update;
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate some help is filling in the gaps in my understanding. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

your code is ok, you can update single document using entire object instead of update every single field. I committed here: https://github.com/sbernardo/spring-issues-examples/tree/main/sof-questions-77623978 full code.

You have 2 chooses:

```java
protected Update createOrderUpdate(Order order) {
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("orderId", order.getOrderId());
    update.set("orderItemList", order.getOrderItemList());
    return update;
}
```

```java
protected Update createOrderUpdateWithAddToSet(Order order) {
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("orderId", order.getOrderId());
    order.getOrderItemList().forEach(oi -> update.addToSet("orderItemList", oi));
    return update;
}
```

The first one replace entire list with input list (only if something changed). The second one add a new orderitem to list if it's already present.

Note: I suggest to use the first one, so you can manage entire list, the second one had to be used only if you want to add something new (not works with update of a single element in array, only for add new one).

I tried the first one in my project (see following code) to manage a single order:

```java
@PatchMapping("orders")
public String myEndpoint() {
    var supplierFirstOrderItem = new Supplier("suppId1", "Supplier1", "PART_NUM122");
    var suppliersFirstOrderItem = List.of(supplierFirstOrderItem);
    var firstOrderItem = new OrderItem("IDIT1", BigDecimal.ONE, "PART_NUM1", "Ordered from Amazon", 1, suppliersFirstOrderItem);
    var orderItems = new ArrayList<>(List.of(firstOrderItem));
    var order = new Order("ID1", orderItems);
    var orders = List.of(order);

    //First upsert -> new order -> INSERT DONE
    var firstUpsert = service.upsertOrders(orders, orderItems);
    log.info("First upsert result: {}", firstUpsert);

    //Second upsert -> add a new order item on an existing order -> UPDATE DONE
    var supplierSecondOrderItem = new Supplier("suppId2", "Supplier2", "PART_NUM211");
    var suppliersSecondOrderItem = List.of(supplierSecondOrderItem);
    var newOrderItem = new OrderItem("IDIT2", BigDecimal.TEN, "PART_NUM2", "Ordered from Ebay", 100, suppliersSecondOrderItem);
    orderItems.add(newOrderItem);
    var secondUpsert = service.upsertOrders(orders, orderItems);
    log.info("Second upsert result: {}", secondUpsert);

    //Third upsert -> modified price on existing order item -> UPDATE DONE
    order.getOrderItemList().getFirst().setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(10000));
    var thirdUpsert = service.upsertOrders(orders, orderItems);
    log.info("Third upsert result: {}", thirdUpsert);

    //Fourth upsert -> writing same order -> NO UPDATE DONE
    var fourthUpsert = service.upsertOrders(orders, orderItems);
    log.info("Fourth upsert result: {}", fourthUpsert);

    var newOrderListOrdered = List.of(newOrderItem, firstOrderItem);
    order.setOrderItemList(newOrderListOrdered);
    //Fifth upsert -> writing same order (different orderItems internal list) -> UPDATE DONE
    var fifthUpsert = service.upsertOrders(orders, orderItems);
    log.info("Fifth upsert result: {}", fifthUpsert);

    var newOrderListDeleteOne = List.of(newOrderItem);
    order.setOrderItemList(newOrderListDeleteOne);
    //Sixth upsert -> writing same order (orderItems deleted one) -> UPDATE DONE
    var sixthUpsert = service.upsertOrders(orders, orderItems);
    log.info("Sixth upsert result: {}", sixthUpsert);

    return sixthUpsert.toString();
}
```

the output log suggest to you what mongo doe

```
First upsert result: AcknowledgedBulkWriteResult{insertedCount=0, matchedCount=0, removedCount=0, modifiedCount=0, upserts=[BulkWriteUpsert{index=0, id=BsonString{value='ID1'}}], inserts=[]}
Second upsert result: AcknowledgedBulkWriteResult{insertedCount=0, matchedCount=1, removedCount=0, modifiedCount=1, upserts=[], inserts=[]}
Third upsert result: AcknowledgedBulkWriteResult{insertedCount=0, matchedCount=1, removedCount=0, modifiedCount=1, upserts=[], inserts=[]}
Fourth upsert result: AcknowledgedBulkWriteResult{insertedCount=0, matchedCount=1, removedCount=0, modifiedCount=0, upserts=[], inserts=[]}
Fifth upsert result: AcknowledgedBulkWriteResult{insertedCount=0, matchedCount=1, removedCount=0, modifiedCount=1, upserts=[], inserts=[]}
Sixth upsert result: AcknowledgedBulkWriteResult{insertedCount=0, matchedCount=1, removedCount=0, modifiedCount=1, upserts=[], inserts=[]}
```

As you can see, only if something change will be updated (order of lists is important! Different order are updated!)

Hope this could be useful! :)

Comment: As you can see from your output the first should have inserted the orders since they do not exist at first, however there are no inserts.

Comment: As you can see from your output the first should have inserted the orders since they do not exist at first, however there are no inserts. Unfortunately, the solution you provided does meet my requirement, i.e. insert if not already in the collection or over write the existing record, that's how upserts work

Comment: The first upsert add document in collection if not exists, is an upsert and as you can see from output return the ID inserted `upserts=[BulkWriteUpsert{index=0, id=BsonString{value='ID1'}}]`. You can try deleting all other upserts and leave the first one only and see on Mongo the document written.

There is only 1 problem with my implementation, if there are, at first upsert, fields into your input entity but not into Update object those will not be inserted. Idk if this is a constraint in your case, if yes sorry, I misunderstood

Comment: I noticed that later. Unfortunately, the upsert does not work in this case like I expected. It completely overwrites all existing orderItem.  Ideally, it should only update existing orderItems if they've changed and leave the others alone, but it doesn't work that way.